# How Can I get Tree.Kind.VARIABLE's Type defined in another java source file when writting sonar plugin rules?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am writting sonar plugin rules, How Can I get Tree.Kind.VARIABLE's Type defined in another java source file?

```
//Cursor.java:
public interface Cursor extends Closeable {
    // TODO.
};

//Engine.java:
public class Engine extends HandlerThread {
    private Cursor mCursor;
    public List<Suggestion> getSuggestions(){
        Cursor photoCursor = contentResolver.query();
        // TODO.
    }
}
```

when sonar plugin rules analysis Engine.java, how cane i get mCursor's type? and photoCursor's type?

My Code is:

```
public class VarCheck extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor
{

    @Override
    public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit()
    {
        return ImmutableList.of(Tree.Kind.VARIABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitNode(Tree tree)
    {
        if (tree.is(Tree.Kind.VARIABLE))
        {
            VariableTree vart = (VariableTree)tree;
            System.out.println("visitNode 02: " + vart.symbol().name() +" "+ vart.symbol().type().name());

            if (vart.symbol().isVariableSymbol())
            {
                VariableSymbol varSymbol = (VariableSymbol)vart.symbol();
                System.out.println("visitNode 03: " + varSymbol.name() 
                                +" "+ varSymbol.type().name()
                                +" "+ varSymbol.type().isSubtypeOf("java.io.Closeable"));
                // Why varSymbol.type().name() is unknownSymbol?
            }

//          vart.accept(visitor);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to Tree.Kind.VARIABLE, cast nodes to VariableTree, access symbol().type() of such VariableTree.

Comment: but soner seems analysiz file by file. and the type class is defined in another java source file. if i merge the two java file, varSymbol.type().name() have value.

Comment: I have paste my Code, Please give me some Suggestion.

Comment: Are you providing byte code during analysis? The symbol resolution can not be completed without it. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode

Comment: thank you very much. it has been resolve when i use sonar.libraries=*.jar when run sonar-runner.